# Как можно получить данные из 3 и более таблиц в SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как можно получить данные из 3 и более таблиц в SQL? Я пытаюсь использовать `INNER JOIN`, но удаётся только получить данные из двух таблиц.

Так я хочу получить :

```
SELECT * FROM table_T A   INNER JOIN  account_T B , bet_T С USING(userid);
```

что бы **table_T**, сравнивалась с **account_T** и **bet_T**.

**Первая таблица:**

```
 |--------------|-----------|
 |userid        |color_name |
 |--------------|-----------|
 |1             |red        |
 |--------------|-----------|
 |2             |blue       |
 |--------------|-----------|
 |3             |red        |
 |--------------|-----------|
 |и.т.д.        | и.т.д     |
```

**Вторая таблица:**

```
|--------------|-----------|
|userid        |List_name  |
|--------------|-----------|
|1             |Tom        |
|--------------|-----------|
|2             |Rise       |
|--------------|-----------|
|3             |Yura       |
|--------------|-----------|
|2             |Bob_name2  |
|--------------|-----------|
| и.т.д        |и.т.д      |
```

**Третья таблица:**

```
|--------------|-----------|
|userid        |Rod__name  |
|--------------|-----------|
|1             |T          |
|--------------|-----------|
|2             |R          |
|--------------|-----------|
|3             |Y          |
|--------------|-----------|
|2             |B          |
|--------------|-----------|
| и.т.д        |и.т.д      |
```

Comment: Можете схему таблиц показать?

Comment: select from A INNER JOIN B USING() INNER JOIN C USING()

Comment: Suvitruf - выложил .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если по `userid` надо всё связать:

```
SELECT * FROM table_T A   
   INNER JOIN  account_T B USING(userid)
   INNER JOIN bet_T С USING(userid);
```